# sudo - new user with command list

Tags: fedora

The following will allow newuser to run any commands anywhere? How can I prevent it by allowing the user to run certain commands only?

```
visudo

## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
newuser ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a command alias for newuser e.g.

```
Cmnd_Alias    NEWUSER_CMDS = /path/to/cmd1, /path/to/cmd2, /path/to/cmd3
```

then use that as part of the user specification

```
newuser ALL=(ALL) NEWUSER_CMDS
```

Comment: On Ubuntu/Debian systems specifically, I noticed the notation:
newuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) NEWUSER_CMDS
This looks like the way SUDO users are defined on that platform through the VISUDO command.  Does Fedora support this as well?

Answer (score 3):

```
newuser ALL=(ALL)       /path/to/your/command
```

Read **User Specification** section in the [`man sudoers`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_sudoers.htm) page for more details.